# Incorrect i2c read bytes

Tags: i2c, arduino, node.js

**NOTE:** Please read the bottom. There's a plot twist.

I'm reading three bytes and my NodeJS code reads `3, 192, 144` in decimal while my logic analyzer reads `0x03, 0xC0, 0x10` which translates to `3, 192, 16`.

Why is the last byte misread as `144` when it should in fact be read as `16`?

Additional info:
This is on a RPi2B on device i2c@10 software i2c device, no pullups, straight from RPi to i2c device.

Here's a comparison between the NodeJS code readout and what i2catalyst shows based on the pulseview annotation export:

As you can see at some points the reads are REALLY OFF especially at address 69... What?!?!

Logic analyser
[image]

NodeJS readout

[image]

I've tried several i2c buses and they all result in incorrect reads.

I have also tried a level shifter that uses the slave system ground and 5v as reference. Still some incorrect readouts.

I have followed the schematics of the original devices and how they're connected to the i2c perfectly to the wire and still incorrect readouts.

**Plot twist:**
Connecting an Arduino Mega 2560 directly to the i2c bus with internal pullups turned ON works perfectly fine. No level shifter, no external pullups, nothing. Just internal pullups and directly to the 5v i2c. Works great.

Comment: I know Rpi python, Arduino C++, I2C. and I have a 4 channel scope.  I don't know node.js and I don't know logic analyzer.  I just installed node Red and wish to get some example code to start learning.  If you can list the C++ and node.js code, I will try to study the code and translate it to Rpi python.  Question - you said you tried several I2C buses.  Are they demux or software bit bang?  I tried both and  found problems with both. :(

Comment: So you successfully set up Rpi I2C buses 3, and 4?  I just tried it yesterday and found it did not work.  So I gave up.  See featured questions number 3.  BTW no hurry at all to show me any node.js code, I am more interested to set up Rpi I2C buses 3 and 4.

Comment: I'll have to think about giving my code away due to the lack of hardware on your side. I'm trying to communicate with old music studio gear that has no support so unless you have the same 90's studio gear that I have, I don't know how my code could be to any use for you.

Comment: About multiple i2c buses, they are software i2c set up on the rpi, here's a pastebin of the i2c part of my `/boot/config.txt` file: https://pastebin.com/ArD4901v

Comment: The buses range from 3 to 10, so 8 new buses

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you are not a hobbyist like me, but on something perhaps commercial.  So I will forget node.js (actually my aim is node-red).  Wow, 8 more I2C software buses, that is too good to be true! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has indicated that a rather unique hardware configuration is required before the code can be exercised.

Comment: @Seamus not off topic. Read the answer.

Comment: @vaid: I'm glad you worked it out. I still feel it's off-topic, but AFAIC that's not a big deal. Someone flagged your question for closure, and I was prompted to vote. I voted for closure, as you see, but what I didn't know was that the system here "threw you under the bus" for rendering an opinion. LOL :)

Comment: @Seamus haha I understand. For anyone reading this: I object as I think that anything RPi related (hardware, software, configuration) is not off topic in an official RPi stack

Answer (score 2):

**Problem solved** by bridging `GND` and `3v` on the RPi with a `1uF` capacitor.

While using a logic analyzer I saw random very short spikes which caused bit flips.

I posted another question asking what the cause of the spikes might be and eventually came across an Arduino thread that suggested to bridge GND and 3v.

This fixed all problems.